# "Logitech C920 HD Pro Webcam - 1080p" Camera is not detecting via navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediadevices

I have the following code to display the available Camera & Mic list on the web page. But unfortunately "**Logitech C920 HD Pro Webcam - 1080p*" Camera is not listed with the below code but the Microphone of the "Logitech" device is showing.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function (devices) {
        for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
              if (devices[i].kind == "videoinput") {   
               console.log("Video Device is : "+devices[i].label);
              }else if( devices[i].kind === "audioinput"  ) {
               console.log("Audio Device is : "+devices[i].label);  
          }
       }
    });
```

I am testing in Mac OS and In Mac OS privacy settings Camera is enabled for the Chrome browser. But when we verify in Zoom, the Camera is listed properly.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: are you trying that before or after getUserMedia?
Does it show up on https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/ ?

Comment: @PhilippHancke We are trying that before the getUserMedia and tried with the above link but the result is the same external camera is not detected. In the Zoom app, it appears.

Comment: you might be hitting https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1338296

Comment: @PhilippHancke It's resolved after disabling and enabling the Camera permission to the Chrome browser from the following path in Mac,
Apple menu > System Preferences, click Security & Privacy - > Camera -> [  Disable & Enable relaunch the Chrome browser ]